# Grub x86-64 equivalent to SendKey

Tags: grub2

GRUB2 has a module for i386 architectures called SendKey. It essentially sends a keystroke, which allowed for me to create a "Page Up" function in my GRUB boot menu.

I'm wondering if there are any ways to accomplish this in an x86 based system?

Thanks!!!

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: 20.04 is the OS version